# Troubles making PCL Xamarin (MonoDroid/MonoTouch) compliant

Tags: c#, xamarin, portable-class-library

We've created a fairly robust PCL that we'd like to use in some Droid/Touch apps via Xamarin.

As of today, I've installed the latest version of Xamarin, and I've set our PCL to [use Profile 158](http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/11/profiles-in-new-portable-world.html).

I've then gone into our project and updated the target assemblies

> - .NET Framework 4.5
> - Windows Phone 8
> - .NET for Windows Store apps
> - Xamarin.Android
> - Xamarin.iOS

After doing that, I'm getting a number of Compilation Failures

[image: compilation errors]
[full size image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMH10.png)

Do I need to replace the `System` dll with the one that ships with Xamarin, or is there something else I need to do in order to get this stuff working?

*note: if I wasn't clear above, there was nothing wrong with the PCL before adding Xamarin targets.*

---

As requested, here's the build output

```text
1>------ Build started: Project: MyApplication.AppCore, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>P:\MyApplication.AppCore\MyApplication.AppCore\Data\DbProviderExtensions.cs(25,29,25,61): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'MyApplication.AppCore.Data.DbProviderExtensions.GetTableName(System.Reflection.MemberInfo)' has some invalid arguments
1>P:\MyApplication.AppCore\MyApplication.AppCore\Data\DbProviderExtensions.cs(25,43,25,57): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Type' to 'System.Reflection.MemberInfo'
1>P:\MyApplication.AppCore\MyApplication.AppCore\Data\DbProviderExtensions.cs(53,29,53,61): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'MyApplication.AppCore.Data.DbProviderExtensions.GetTableName(System.Reflection.MemberInfo)' has some invalid arguments
1>P:\MyApplication.AppCore\MyApplication.AppCore\Data\DbProviderExtensions.cs(53,43,53,57): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Type' to 'System.Reflection.MemberInfo'
1>P:\MyApplication.AppCore\MyApplication.AppCore\Data\DbProviderExtensions.cs(55,38,55,71): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'MyApplication.AppCore.Data.DbProviderExtensions.GetTableName(System.Reflection.MemberInfo)' has some invalid arguments
1>P:\MyApplication.AppCore\MyApplication.AppCore\Data\DbProviderExtensions.cs(55,52,55,67): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Type' to 'System.Reflection.MemberInfo'
1>P:\MyApplication.AppCore\MyApplication.AppCore\Data\DbProviderExtensions.cs(85,29,85,61): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'MyApplication.AppCore.Data.DbProviderExtensions.GetTableName(System.Reflection.MemberInfo)' has some invalid arguments
1>P:\MyApplication.AppCore\MyApplication.AppCore\Data\DbProviderExtensions.cs(85,43,85,57): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Type' to 'System.Reflection.MemberInfo'
1>P:\MyApplication.AppCore\MyApplication.AppCore\Data\DbProviderExtensions.cs(102,29,102,61): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'MyApplication.AppCore.Data.DbProviderExtensions.GetTableName(System.Reflection.MemberInfo)' has some invalid arguments
1>P:\MyApplication.AppCore\MyApplication.AppCore\Data\DbProviderExtensions.cs(102,43,102,57): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Type' to 'System.Reflection.MemberInfo'
1>P:\MyApplication.AppCore\MyApplication.AppCore\Data\DbProviderExtensions.cs(120,29,120,61): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'MyApplication.AppCore.Data.DbProviderExtensions.GetTableName(System.Reflection.MemberInfo)' has some invalid arguments
1>P:\MyApplication.AppCore\MyApplication.AppCore\Data\DbProviderExtensions.cs(120,43,120,57): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Type' to 'System.Reflection.MemberInfo'
1>P:\MyApplication.AppCore\MyApplication.AppCore\Data\DbProviderExtensions.cs(144,29,144,61): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'MyApplication.AppCore.Data.DbProviderExtensions.GetTableName(System.Reflection.MemberInfo)' has some invalid arguments
1>P:\MyApplication.AppCore\MyApplication.AppCore\Data\DbProviderExtensions.cs(144,43,144,57): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Type' to 'System.Reflection.MemberInfo'
1>P:\MyApplication.AppCore\MyApplication.AppCore\Data\DbProviderExtensions.cs(171,41,171,54): error CS1061: 'System.Type' does not contain a definition for 'GetProperties' and no extension method 'GetProperties' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Type' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
1>P:\MyApplication.AppCore\MyApplication.AppCore\Data\DbProviderExtensions.cs(239,25,239,38): error CS1061: 'System.Type' does not contain a definition for 'GetInterfaces' and no extension method 'GetInterfaces' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Type' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
1>P:\MyApplication.AppCore\MyApplication.AppCore\Infrastructure\AutoMapper.cs(18,54,18,67): error CS1061: 'System.Type' does not contain a definition for 'GetProperties' and no extension method 'GetProperties' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Type' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
1>P:\MyApplication.AppCore\MyApplication.AppCore\Infrastructure\AutoMapper.cs(47,54,47,67): error CS1061: 'System.Type' does not contain a definition for 'GetProperties' and no extension method 'GetProperties' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Type' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
1>P:\MyApplication.AppCore\MyApplication.AppCore\Infrastructure\AutoMapper.cs(78,50,78,63): error CS1061: 'System.Type' does not contain a definition for 'GetProperties' and no extension method 'GetProperties' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Type' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
1>P:\MyApplication.AppCore\MyApplication.AppCore\Infrastructure\AutoMapper.cs(100,50,100,63): error CS1061: 'System.Type' does not contain a definition for 'GetProperties' and no extension method 'GetProperties' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Type' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
1>P:\MyApplication.AppCore\MyApplication.AppCore\Infrastructure\MigrationRunner.cs(61,40,61,48): error CS1061: 'System.Type' does not contain a definition for 'Assembly' and no extension method 'Assembly' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Type' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
1>P:\MyApplication.AppCore\MyApplication.AppCore\Infrastructure\MigrationRunner.cs(62,77,62,93): error CS1061: 'System.Type' does not contain a definition for 'IsAssignableFrom' and no extension method 'IsAssignableFrom' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Type' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
1>P:\MyApplication.AppCore\MyApplication.AppCore\Repositories\RepositoryBase.cs(60,30,60,50): error CS0117: 'System.Reflection.Assembly' does not contain a definition for 'GetExecutingAssembly'
2>------ Build started: Project: MyApplication.AppCore.Tests, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
2>  P:\MyApplication.AppCore\MyApplication.AppCore.Tests\x86\sqlite3.dll
2>  1 File(s) copied
2>  P:\MyApplication.AppCore\MyApplication.AppCore.Tests\x64\sqlite3.dll
2>  1 File(s) copied
2>  MyApplication.AppCore.Tests -> P:\MyApplication.AppCore\MyApplication.AppCore.Tests\bin\Debug\MyApplication.AppCore.Tests.dll
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 1 failed, 4 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

---

Not sure if seeing some lines of code will help but, here goes

```
    public static void Create<TModel> ( this IDbProvider dbProvider, TModel model ) where TModel : class, new()
    {

        var tableName = GetTableName( typeof( TModel ) ); // LINE 25

    }
```

```
foreach ( 
    var collection in model.GetType()
                           .GetProperties() // LINE 171
                           .Where(
                               property =>
                               property.GetCustomAttributes( typeof( ManyToManyAttribute ), true ).Any() ) )
{
        if ( !IsGenericList( collection.PropertyType ) )  // LINE 176
            throw new ArgumentException( "The property must be an ICollection<>" );
}
```

```
    private static bool IsGenericList ( Type type )
    {
        if ( type == null )
            throw new ArgumentNullException( "type" );

        return type.GetInterfaces() // LINE 239
                   .Where( i => i.IsGenericType )
                   .Any( i => i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof( ICollection<> ) );
    }
```

Comment: Is it forcing you to use the new Reflection API?

Comment: @atomaras I didn't know there was a new Reflection API.

Comment: Please show some code, for example around lines 25, 171 and 239 in *DbProviderExtensions.cs*.

Comment: I added a couple of lines of code, but I'm not sure they'll help. As I said, this was all working before trying to add Xamarin targets to the PCL.

Comment: @AndersGustafsson I've posted some code... not sure if it's useful.

Comment: 78/111 work better indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Profile158 targets Silverlight 5 in addition to the other targets you listed.  What profile were you targeting before you added Xamarin support?

One thing to try is to target Profile78, which should be the set of platforms you listed.

If that doesn't work, can you update your answer with the errors copied from the build output?  The errors in the screenshot are hard to read and it's not clear if they are all coming from the same project.

Comment: the previous Profile was 104. All errors are from the same project, and there's a link below the screenshot to the full sized image.

Comment: @ChaseFlorell Can you try changing it back to Profile104 and seeing if it still compiles successfully?  Also, PCLs shouldn't have any explicit references to .NET Framework assemblies such as System.DLL or mscorlib, so if you have any of those in your project try removing them.

Comment: I've actually started refactoring the project to use the Reflection specified for WinRT applications. Appears to be getting somewhere... will post findings.